# How to correctly manage memory stack and view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, viewcontroller

I'm really struggling with this basic iOS programming stuff but I just can't figure out whats happening and how to solve it.

I have my main Login controller that detects when a user is logged in and presents next controller if auth succeed:

```
@interface LoginViewController (){

    //Main root instance
    RootViewController *mainPlatformRootControler;
}

-(void)loggedInActionWithToken:(NSString *)token anonymous:(BOOL)isAnon{
    NSLog(@"User loged in.");

    mainPlatformRootControler = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootViewCOntrollerStoryIdentifier"];

    [self presentViewController:mainPlatformRootControler animated:YES completion:^{

    }];

}
```

And that works well, no problem.

My trouble is handling logout. How do I delete completely the RootViewController instance and show a new one?

I can see that RootViewController instances are stacking cause I have multiple observers and after a logout and then login they are called multiple times (as many times I exit and re-enter).

I've tried the following with no success:

First detecting logout in RootViewController and dismissing:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"shouldLogOut" object:nil];

            }];
```

And then in LoginViewController:

```
-(void)shouldLogOut:(NSNotification *) not{
    NSLog(@"No user signed in");
    mainPlatformRootControler = NULL;
    mainPlatformRootControler = nil;
}
```

So how can I handle this? I know its a basic memory handle stuff but I just don't know how?

Comment: Why do you need to keep `mainPlatformRootControler` on `LoginViewController`? If `RootViewController` is presented from `LoginViewController`, you can get `loginViewController` from `RootViewController` by using `self.presentingViewController` and after that call a method without using notification

Comment: "I can see that RootViewController instances are stacking cause I have multiple observers " This is wrong, notificationcenter does not retain observers..

Comment: please provide the code where you add and "remove" RootViewController from your navigation stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem** is likely that you are never dismissing the `RootViewController` when logout has happened. By setting the property `mainPlatformRootControler` to `nil`, you are just relinquishing ownership of the object from the perspective of `LoginViewController`. That says nothing about anything else that also owns a reference to the object behind `mainPlatformRootControler`.

**To fix this** add a notification observer inside `RootViewController` for the **logout** notification, and when that's received, dismiss itself via `dismiss(animated:completion)`

**Bonus** You also don't need the property `mainPlatformRootControler` if all you are doing is saving it around to nil it out. By properly dismissing it (in the manner I wrote above), it will automatically be cleaned up, and thus don't need to worry about `nil`ing it out either. (Now if you have other reasons for keeping `mainPlatformRootControler` around, then don't delete it obviously).

Comment: Andy Im sorry I completely forgot to say Im dismissing the RootViewController inside it. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to observe "shouldLogOut" in viewDidLoad should be like below:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(shouldLogout:) name:@"shouldLogout" object:nil];
```

and after that in dismissViewControllerAnimated should be like below:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"shouldLogOut" object:nil];
    }];
```

you need to define shouldLogOut: selector in login view controller

```
-(void)shouldLogOut:(NSNotification *) not{
    mainPlatformRootControler = nil;
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Because login and logout is the one-time process, so after login, instead of presenting new controller just replace login controller with main controller.

Let's understand this:
You have main application delegate with window.

Code in didFinishLaunch:

```
if (loggedIn) {
     self.window = yourMainController
} else {
     self.window = loginController
}
```

Code in LoginController:
LoginController will have instance of AppDelegate, and after login, you have to change

> appDelegate.window = mainController

Code in MainController:
MainController will have instance of AppDelegate, and after logout, you have to change

> appDelegate.window = loginController

I hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Notification observer in `viewDidLoad` of your `LoginViewController` look like below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shouldLogOut:) name:@"shouldLogOut" object:nil];
```

I guess you missed this, then your login class can not receive notification after `RootViewController` dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said there are multiple observer creates issue, then you must have to remove your observer when you don't need it.

**In your RootViewController**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated  
{  
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];  

  // Add observer
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shouldLogout:) name:@"shouldLogout" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Remove observer by name
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"shouldLogout" object:nil];
}
```

So in this way you don't have to think about your RootViewController is in stack or it is loaded from fresh etc. Because actual problem is with your observer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many correct ways to manage view hierarchies, but I'll share one way I have found to be simple and affective.

Basically, I swap out the primary `UIWindow`'s `rootViewController` at log out/in. Additionally, I programmatically provide the `rootViewController` rather than letting `@UIApplicationMain` to load the initial view controller. The benefit of doing this is that during app launch, if the user is logged in, then the `Login.storyboard` never has to be loaded.

The `show` function can be configured to suite your style, but I like cross dissolve transitions as they are very simple.

[image]

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    lazy var window: UIWindow? = {

        let window = UIWindow()
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return window
    }()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Your own logic here
        let isLoggedIn = false

        if isLoggedIn {
            show(MainViewController(), animated: false)
        } else {
            show(LoginViewController(), animated: false)
        }

        return true
    }
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        let logoutButton = UIButton()
        logoutButton.setTitle("Log In", for: .normal)
        logoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(login), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(logoutButton)
        logoutButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [logoutButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
             logoutButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)]
        )

        self.view = view
    }

    @objc
    func login() {
        AppDelegate.shared.show(MainViewController())
    }
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        let logoutButton = UIButton()
        logoutButton.setTitle("Log Out", for: .normal)
        logoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(logout), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(logoutButton)
        logoutButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [logoutButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
             logoutButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            ]
        )

        self.view = view
    }

    @objc
    func logout() {
        AppDelegate.shared.show(LoginViewController())
    }
}

extension AppDelegate {

    static var shared: AppDelegate {
        // swiftlint:disable force_cast
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        // swiftlint:enable force_cast
    }
}

private let kTransitionSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

extension AppDelegate {

    /// Animates changing the `rootViewController` of the main application.
    func show(_ viewController: UIViewController,
              animated: Bool = true,
              options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.transitionCrossDissolve, .curveEaseInOut],
              completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

        guard let window = window else { return }

        if animated == false {
            window.rootViewController = viewController
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            kTransitionSemaphore.wait()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let duration = 0.35

                let previousAreAnimationsEnabled = UIView.areAnimationsEnabled
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

                UIView.transition(with: window, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {
                    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
                }, completion: { _ in
                    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(previousAreAnimationsEnabled)

                    kTransitionSemaphore.signal()
                    completion?()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is a complete example, you can create a new project, clear out the "Main Interface" field, and then put this code in the app delegate.

The resulting transition:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dismissing the RootViewController and you nil the reference after logout but the instance is not released, the only other possibility is that something else is keeping a reference to the RootViewController. You probably have a retain cycle.
A retain cycle happens if two objects have a strong reference to each other. And because an object cannot be deallocated until all of its strong references are released, then you have a memory leak.

Examples of retain cycle include:

```
    RootViewController *root = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    AnOtherViewController *another = [[AnOtherViewController alloc] init];
    //The two instances reference each other
    root.anotherInstance = another;
    another.rootInstance = root;
```

Or

```
    self.block = ^{
                //self is captured strongly by the block
                //and the block is captured strongly by the self instance
                NSLog(@"%@", self);
            };
```

The solution is to use a weak pointer for one of the references. Since a weak pointer is one that does not retain its target.
e.g.

```
@property(weak) RootViewController *anotherInstance;
```

And

```
_typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self
self.block = ^{
             _typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf
            //self is captured strongly by the block
            //and the block is captured strongly by the self instance
            NSLog(@"%@", strongSelf);
        };
```